# searching for records based off of results from other results

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have four kinds of records. Teams. Coaches. Players. and Families.

Teams have a one to many association with Coaches.
Coaches have a one to one association with Players.
Players have a many to one association with Families.

What I need to find are specific families that are associated with certain Teams. However due to their separation i can't just go `Team.last.family`.

Is there a way to leap over the Players and Coaches and do a query from the clinics straight to the family?

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of the relationships of your models to better grasp the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will need to make use of the [joins](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) method.
If you provide more details of your model code and schema we could provide more details, but it will be something along the lines of.

```
Family.joins(some_join_object).where(some_sql_search_string)
```

Once you have a join table that includes all the columns you want, specify the conditions you would like to filter on.

```
Family.joins(:players, :coaches, :teams).where("families.name='Wesley' and teams.name='Crushers'")
```

Here is an example from the provided link.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tags
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  has_one :guest
end

class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

> 12.1.3.2 Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)

```
Category.joins(articles: [{ comments: :guest }, :tags])
```

> This produces:
>
> SELECT categories.* FROM categories   INNER JOIN articles ON
>   articles.category_id = categories.id   INNER JOIN comments ON
>   comments.article_id = articles.id   INNER JOIN guests ON
>   guests.comment_id = comments.id   INNER JOIN tags ON tags.article_id =
>   articles.id
>
> Or, in English: "return all categories that have articles, where those
>   articles have a comment made by a guest, and where those articles also
>   have a tag."